# FOR LOOP, for drawing 2 horizontal lines with a specific formula

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, secure-trading

**For Loop issue to print 2 horizontal lines as per formula.**

**WHEN THE SECURITY, PRICE/CLOSE VALUE CHANGES, THE OLD LINES MUST BE DELETED AUTOMATICALLY AND REPLACED WITH NEW LINES AS PER MENTIONED FORMULA**

```
//@version=4
study("g", overlay=true)





float g_90 = 0
float g_90_1 = 0

for g_90 = 0 to 1000000                                                     // 1000000 can be any infinite number
    g_90_1          = g_90 + 1                                              // second variable is 1 value above previous variable g_90             
    g_90_return     = 4*(g_90*g_90) + 7*(g_90) + 4                          //assign a variable g_90_return; to the formula1 = 4*(g_90*g_90) + 7*(g_90) + 4  to plot a horizontal line
    g_90_1_return   = 4*(g_90_1*g_90_1) + 7*(g_90_1) + 4                    //assign a variable g_90_1_return; to the formula2 = 4*(g_90_1*g_90_1) + 7*(g_90_1) + 4  with second variable to plot another horizontal line

    if( (g_90_return < close) and ( g_90_1_return > close) )                // if close > formula1 and close < formula2, draw both the hroizontal lines; as long as price is contained within them
        hline(g_90_return   , color = color.blue, linewidth= 4)
        hline(g_90_1_return , color = color.blue,  linewidth= 4)
    else
        g_90 := g_90 + 1                                                    // run loop again with incremental value
```

Answer (score 1):

`hline()` can't be used in `for` loops. You could use [`line.new()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_line%7Bdot%7Dnew).

Comment: Thank you for that. I will work on the same.